# Create numbered sets in a column with bash commands

Tags: bash, awk, text, set

I have this type of file - 2 column list with genes in 1st and chromosomal position in second column.

```
        1:924024
        1:924310
SAMD11  1:930353
SAMD11  1:930939
NOC2L   1:944858
NOC2L   1:946247
KLHL17  1:960891
KLHL17  1:961945
```

It is needed to be converted to this list type, so that 2 column format is saved. Each set number goes for each gene (not each row).

```
1:na         1:924024
2:na         1:924310
3:SAMD11    1:930353
3:SAMD11    1:930939
4:NOC2L     1:944858
4:NOC2L     1:946247
5:KLHL17    1:960891
5:KLHL17    1:961945
```

I tried to use this row:

```
   awk -F "\t" -v OFS="\t" '{ ($1=="")? ($1=NR":na"):($1=NR":"$1)}1' test.txt
```

however,
this makes row numbering, and I get

```
1:na    1:924024
2:na    1:924310
3:SAMD11    1:930353
4:SAMD11    1:930939
5:NOC2L     1:944858
6:NOC2L     1:946247
7:KLHL17    1:960891
8:KLHL17    1:961945
```

instead of desired

```
1:na         1:924024
2:na         1:924310
3:SAMD11    1:930353
3:SAMD11    1:930939
4:NOC2L     1:944858
4:NOC2L     1:946247
5:KLHL17    1:960891
5:KLHL17    1:961945
```

Is it possible to do such thing with bash?
Thank you!

Comment: Are the genes always grouped by name in the first column as shown in your sample input or can, for example, another `SAMD11` or empty gene name appear after a `NOC2L` line?

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples only, please try following.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ OFS="\t" }
/^ +/{
  $1=++count":na" OFS $1
  print
  next
}
prev!=$1{
  count++
}
{
  $1=count ":" $1
  $1=$1
  split($1,arr,":")
  prev=arr[2]
}
1
' Input_file  | column -t -s $'\t'
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
awk '                                ##Starting awk program from here.
BEGIN{ OFS="\t" }                    ##Starting BEGIN section which has OFS as tab here.
/^ +/{                               ##Checking condition if line starts from space.
  $1=++count":na" OFS $1             ##Adding count :na OFS along with $1 in $1 itself.
  print                              ##printing current line here.
  next                               ##next will skip all further statements from here.
}
prev!=$1{                            ##Checking if prev is NOT equals to $1 then do following.
  count++                            ##Increasing count with 1 here.
}
{
  $1=count ":" $1                    ##Adding count colon $1 into $1 here.
  $1=$1                              ##Re-assigning $1 to itself here.
  split($1,arr,":")                  ##Splitting $1 into arr here.
  prev=arr[2]                        ##Assigning 2nd element into prev here of array arr.
}
1                                    ##printing current line.
' Input_file  | column -t -s $'\t'   ##Sending output to column column command as an Input.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS="\t"} 
             {c+=!($1 in a)
              if($1=="") $1="na"
              else a[$1]
              print c":"$1, $2}' file | column -t 


1:na      1:924024
2:na      1:924310
3:SAMD11  1:930353
3:SAMD11  1:930939
4:NOC2L   1:944858
4:NOC2L   1:946247
5:KLHL17  1:960891
5:KLHL17  1:961945
```

Comment: Should 1 & 2 be in the same group?

Comment: why? neither the question nor the expected output implies this.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- the 'set number' is specific to field #1 (`gene`); field #2 (`chromosomal position`) has no bearing on the value of the `set number`
- data is already sorted by field #1 (`gene`)
- input delimiter is white space (ie, could be space or tab)
- output delimiter is tab (for sake of this answer)

One `awk` idea:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS="\t"}            # output field separator = "tab"
NF==1 { print ++n":na",$1        # if line contains one field (ie, is missing the gene) then print our ":na" line ...
        next                     # and skip to next line of input
      }
      { if ( $1 != lastgene)     # if this is a new gene then ...
           { n++                 # increment our line counter and ...
             lastgene=$1         # make note of the new gene
           }
        print n":"$1,$2          # print current line
      }

' genes.dat
```

This generates:

```
1:na    1:924024
2:na    1:924310
3:SAMD11        1:930353
3:SAMD11        1:930939
4:NOC2L 1:944858
4:NOC2L 1:946247
5:KLHL17        1:960891
5:KLHL17        1:961945
```

**NOTE:** output formatting could be modified (eg, use `printf` to line up columns) based on OP's actual requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="\t" }
$1 == "" {
    $1 = "na"
    delete geneNr[$1]
}
!($1 in geneNr) {
    geneNr[$1] = ++numGenes
}
{
    $1 = geneNr[$1] ":" $1
    print
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
1:na    1:924024
2:na    1:924310
3:SAMD11        1:930353
3:SAMD11        1:930939
4:NOC2L 1:944858
4:NOC2L 1:946247
5:KLHL17        1:960891
5:KLHL17        1:961945
```